# Dummy Update to existing data

Tags: apex, trigger, data-loader

I have a deployed a trigger to production and i need to run the trigger to update the existing records.Is there any way to run the trigger for existing data  other than pulling the existing records using dataloader and doing a dummy update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can attempt to update all records at once with:

```
 update [SELECT Id FROM Account];
```

Of course, this only works if you're fairly confident that you won't bump into governor limits.

I've often done this using something like `SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE Id > 'someId' ORDER BY Id LIMIT 1000`, where I check the logs for the last Id used.

Answer (score 3):

You can move the logic to update the records to a separate class and make the method as public static and accept a `List<<your object>>`. Then call this method from your trigger. In order to run this for the existing data, call this method from Developer console or the anonymous code in your eclipse ide. An example would be:

```
public class AccountHelper {
   public static void changeOwner(List<Account> listAccounts) {
        // logic to change the owner
   }
}

trigger AccountTrigger on (after insert, after update) {
    AccountHelper.changeOwner(Trigger.new);
}
```

from your developer console:

```
List<Account> listAccounts = [SELECT Id, ... FROM Account WHERE <condition>];
AccountHelper.changeOwner(listAccounts);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hari, welcome to salesforce stackexchange! Signing your posts is generally frowned upon here, so I've removed it while adding code formatting to your answer.

Comment: Peterson - Sorry didn't know about that. Thanks for the info, though.

Comment: Not a problem at all - glad to have you here!